# How to write BDD test case to validate the column names in UI displayed?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I have an UI that displays data in tabular format. This table has 9 columns. I need to write the BDD scenario which validates the names of all these columns. I am not sure which of the following is the correct approach.(included only the last "Then" statement after navigating to desired UI)

Approach 1:

```
Then UI should include bill details in tabular format with "Bill ID" "Payment Type" "Facility Name" "BillAccount/Master Account" "Supplier Name" "Statement Date" "Due Date" "Total Amount Due" and "Bill Image" columns
```

Step Definition:

```
[Then(@"UI should include bill details in tabular format with ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" and ""(.*)"" columns")]
public void ThenUIShouldIncludeBillDetailsInTabularFormatWithAndColumns(string p0, string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5, string p6, string p7, string p8)
```

Here I can directly get the expected column name using string p0 value and compare with the actual value. I can do the same for all 9 column names

Approach 2:

```
Then UI should include bill details with below columns
    | col1         | col2         |  | col3          | col4                       |  | col5          | col6           |  | col7     | col8             | col9       |
    | Bill ID      | Payment Type |  | Facility Name | BillAccount/Master Account |  | Supplier Name | Statement Date |  | Due Date | Total Amount Due | Bill Image |
```

In this approach, I need to know the best way to read the column names mentioned as parameter values. One option is to create a custom class with 9 string fields and use the respective class in `table.createInstance()` method.

Please suggest me the best way.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way is subjective, but favor readability for BDD tests.

Your second approach would be the best, because the scenario is easiest to read. Besides, the `table.CompareToSet(...)` extension method makes for easy comparisons of things.

Whether using Selenium or some other UI automation framework, you need to scrape the table values from the screen and assign them to a collection:

```cs
IEnumerable<BillDetailRow> billDetails = somePageModel.GetBillDetails();

table.CompareToSet(billDetails);
```

If the order of the items matters, use the `table.CompareToSet(billDetails, true);` overload.